# R-CMD-check GitHub Actions workflow failing on warnings/notes

Tags: r, github, github-actions, r-package

In the repository of my R package, I set a GitHub Actions workflow for the `R CMD check` command, following the examples shown in the `usethis` package documentation (with the `usethis::use_github_actions()` command). 
I noticed that my workflow is marked as `Fail` even if only warnings and notes are found (i.e. no errors).

Is there a way to mark runs without errors as a `Pass`? Like a flag in the `.github/workflows/R-CMD-check.yaml` file

The following is a part of my current `.yaml` file. I tried adding the `R_REMOTES_NO_ERRORS_FROM_WARNINGS: true` line but the change was uneffective.

```
name: R-CMD-check

jobs:
  R-CMD-check:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      R_REMOTES_NO_ERRORS_FROM_WARNINGS: true
      GITHUB_PAT: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      R_KEEP_PKG_SOURCE: yes
    steps:
      ...
```

Answer (score 3):

I realized the problem was in the actual part of the file calling the `rcmdcheck()` function, which is automatically created and uses an already implemented workflow, `check-r-package`.

Therefore, the problem is solved by modifying the `.github/workflows/R-CMD-check.yaml` file as follows:

```
      - uses: r-lib/actions/check-r-package@v1
        with:
          error-on: '"error"'
```

In this way, we can set the arguments to the `rcmdcheck::rcmdcheck(...)` command which is internally run by `r-lib/actions/check-r-package@v1`. Under `with`, you can set the arguments of `rcmdcheck(...)` as you wish, and you can modify the internal call to the function.

Anyway, at this link https://github.com/r-lib/actions you can find the arguments/flags you can use in the workflows already implemented, also in the workflows to install the dependencies ecc.